# How can i play online song in android default music player

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.music","com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity");
                        intent.setComponent(comp);
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

i try below code but not work properly and i also try This code

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(listSongUrl.get(position));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
                        startActivity(intent);
```